# How to apply different styles to TreeNode for different States?

Tags: css, smartgwt, treegrid

I'm working on Java, SmartGWT 2.5 & Mozilla FF 3.6.x. I'm using `Tree`, `TreeGrid` & `TreeNode` in my application. My question is: I want to apply different styles to a `TreeNode` for 3 different States of the `TreeNode`. The States are: Enabled, Selected, Over(Mouse Hover). How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override getBaseStyle() or getCellCSSText().  There's an example of each here:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_appearance_hilite_add

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_appearance_hilite_replace

This same API applies to TreeGrid because ListGrid is it's superclass.  The "Record" parameter to these methods are your TreeNode.