# Styling a smartgwt TreeGrid

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, treegrid

I have come a long way styling a certain treegrid, attempting to make it not look like a treegrid :D I've removed the connector lines, open/close buttons, icons to only have text and indentation.

However, for some reason when I hover a row, the background still changes to an shade, just like on any regular listgrid when you go over a row. It looks like it's a layer coming over my usual row. Any ideas how to disable this behaviour alltogether and only rely on CSS?

Then, a second issue: how can I create a margin between the rows/nodes in my TreeGrid? Each item has a border set by CSS, and I can't manage to make subsequent rows not sticking together. I need a few pixels in between them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you don't want hover on TreeNode then disable it.

yourGrid.setShowRollOver(false);

for second issue, i guess you just need to increase the height of cell.

yourGrid.setCellHeight(40);

Answer (score 0):

For your first question: you can use the following:

```
treeNode.setCustomStyle(stylename);
```

You may also take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441631/how-to-apply-different-styles-to-treenode-for-different-states).

Besides there are so many properties related to style in **ListGrid** such as following:

```
grid.setTallBaseStyle(stylename);
grid.setRecordBaseStyleProperty(stylename);
```

& many more. You should try them to achieve your desired look for the Tree..