# smartgwt highlighting Tree node text

Tags: css, gwt, tree, smartgwt, treegrid

I want to highlight/ change color of the text of a tree node in smartgwt. I tried TreeGrid.selectRecord(node) which works, but this creates a background for the width of the tree.

I just want to highlight the text(title of the node) or change the text color of the title of the node.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
treeNode.setCustomStyle(stylename);
```

You may also take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441631/how-to-apply-different-styles-to-treenode-for-different-states).